# Unable to select the values from dropdown and also to print the same

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

Here is my code:

```
        WebElement pooldropdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/section[2]/div[1]/select"));
        Select sel = new Select(pooldropdown);
        List<WebElement> list =  sel.getOptions();
        System.out.println("Number of Pool items : "+list.size()); 

          for(int i =0; i>list.size() ; i++){
          System.out.println(list .get(i).getText());

          }
```

HTML Code:

```html
<section id="content-data"><div class="cpoolSelection" id="poolSelection"><div class="cpoolLabel" id="poolLabel">Select Pool : </div><select onchange="callSetPoolId()" id="poolFilter" style="display: none;"><option value="0"> All </option><option selected="true" value="1">National</option><option value="2">Special Reserve</option><option value="3">NAT_PERM</option><option value="4">NE_PERM</option><option value="5">SE_PERM</option><option value="6">NC_PERM</option><option value="7">SC_PERM</option><option value="8">SCNW_PERM</option><option value="9">NC4C_PERM</option><option value="10">RSC_PERM</option><option value="11">A&amp;D_PERM</option><option value="12">FCP</option><option value="13">R&amp;D</option><option value="14">Support</option><option value="15">Other</option><option value="17">RSA Lease</option></select><button class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all poolClass ui-state-active" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 228px;">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
<span>National</span>
</button>
</div>
```

I am unable to select the drop down values using above selenium code.
Please help me to select the values from drop down and validate all the options in drop down.

Comment: Can you share the website where you are performing this ? I guess some wait problem or xpath problem.

Comment: what error are you getting plz post the error

Comment: please share the code for `sel.getOptions()`

Comment: Is `System.out.println("Number of Pool items : "+list.size()); ` giving you the correct size?

Comment: Hi Kishan, Thanks for your Answers. I am not getting any error.  System.out.println("Number of Pool items : "+list.size()); is able to print Number of Pool items : 17, later nothing happens. When I debug the code get(i).getText() .It says "This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc”

Answer (score 0):

Improve your for loop code please :

```
for(int i =0; i>list.size() ; i++){
          System.out.println(list .get(i).getText());

          }
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++){ //observe the sign change
          System.out.println(list .get(i).getText());

          }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answers. I did change as suggested (> to <), still unable to print  the options within the dropdown

Comment: @Ambika I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are 2 Tasks in your question.
1. selecting values form drop down and 
2. validating options

 WebElement pooldropdown=driver.findElement(By.id("cpoolLabel"));
        Select sel = new Select(pooldropdown);
// ways to select values from drop-down
         sel.selectByValue(“10”);
         sel.selectByIndex(2);
         sel.selectByVisibleText(“SCNW_PERM”);

        List<WebElement> list =  sel.getOptions();
        System.out.println("Number of Pool items : "+list.size()); 

          for(int i =0; i>list.size() ; i++){
          System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());

          }
```